# Converting Arraylist into Observable list without creating a whole new list class?

Tags: java, android, observable, rx-java, rx-android

I have an `Arraylist<Object>` and I am trying it make it `Observable` using `rxJava` so that all operations like clear, add and remove, etc I can get the listeners.

I saw this post [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rxjava/ihlilkKW0BM) for adding a watcher for add events.

Can anyone please tell me is there any approach directly converting my ArrayList into an Observable list, instead of creating an observable list class and creating all methods for it, and changing all `newArrayList<>` to new `ObservableCLass<>`.

Comment: A colleague of mine was working on reactive key-value observing for Kotlin. You might try taking a look here. 

[RxMutableListWrapper.kt](https://github.com/cardinalblue/kotlin-delegate-rx-properties/blob/dev_rx_mutable_list/rx-delegate/src/main/java/com/cardinalblue/RxMutableListWrapper.kt.)

Basically, he uses RxRelay and a Wrapper class to listen for additions and removals. Diff-ing does become a bit complex but should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to use LiveDataand subscribe in it